# .sh file in CronTab not working

Tags: shell

I got the following script from net. I changed some things (the function init() has my details, and there was the word function written before each function, which I removed) but now it's not working on crontab. It's working good on terminal.

Crontab:

`30 2 * * * bash /var/www/html/final.sh`

.sh file:

```
 #!/bin/bash

main(){ init chkBackupDir }

init() { BACKUP_DIR="/var/www/html/backups" DB_USER="wordpressU" DB_PASSWORD="wordpressP" DB_NAME="wordpress" DOC_ROOT="/var/www/html/wordpress" DAYS_TO_KEEP_BACKUP="5" }

chkBackupDir() { if [ ! -d "$BACKUP_DIR" ]; then mkdir "$BACKUP_DIR" fi bakupDocRoot }

bakupDocRoot() { tar -cjf "$BACKUP_DIR"/doc_root_backup-$(date
+%d-%m-%y).tar.bz2 --directory="$DOC_ROOT" . if [[ -e "$BACKUP_DIR"/doc_root_backup-$(date +%d-%m-%y).tar.bz2 ]]; then bakupDatabase else echo "Backup failed for document root on your server. Please check manually" fi }

bakupDatabase() { `which mysqldump` -u "$DB_USER" -p"$DB_PASSWORD" "$DB_NAME" > "$BACKUP_DIR"/"$DB_NAME"-$(date +%d-%m-%y).sql | tee "$BACKUP_DIR"/backup.log tar -cjf "$BACKUP_DIR"/"$DB_NAME"-$(date
+%d-%m-%y).tar.bz2 "$BACKUP_DIR"/"$DB_NAME"-$(date +%d-%m-%y).sql --remove-files 2> $BACKUP_DIR/tar.log if [[ -e "$BACKUP_DIR"/"$DB_NAME"-$(date +%d-%m-%y).tar.bz2 ]]; then createTar else echo "Backup failed for database on your server. Please check manually"  fi }

createTar() { cd "$BACKUP_DIR" tar -cf backup-$(date +%d-%m-%y).tar doc_root_backup-$(date +%d-%m-%y).tar.bz2 "$DB_NAME"-$(date
+%d-%m-%y).tar.bz2 --remove-files 2> final.log deleteOldBackup }

deleteOldBackup() { `which find` "$BACKUP_DIR"/ -mtime
+"$DAYS_TO_KEEP_BACKUP" -exec rm {} \; >> "$BACKUP_DIR"/delete.log }

main  # End
```

What is the solution pls?

Comment: try copy/paste this code into http://shellcheck.net and see if it flags any issues. Correct those and test. If still not working update your Q with corrected code. Also you need to define "not working". Please include error messages and other evidence (i.e. expected file to be create /dir/a/b/c/myFile, but not listed by `ls -l /dir/a/b/c/my*` for example). Good luck.

Comment: You need to set your `PATH` so that all the binaries you refer to can be found... `mkdir`, `mysqldump` etc. You don't need to execute it with `bash` from `crontab` because it already has a shebang at the start so it is obvious which interpreter you want used.

Comment: It's done!! Thank you!